# How can I implement my custom landing page into Wordpress?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currenty working in a project that runs on Node.js on Docker. For that, I have built a landing page using Bootstrap. In the  middle of project, our team would implement Wordpress as CMS.
Can I use that landing page inside Wordpress CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just create your page in the WordPress. Grab the id of the page and then use it to create your file. For instance, page-12.php and then copy this file in the root of your theme directory. You can copy your bootstrap/html code to this file. And then simply go to [www.yourdomain.com/landingpage](http://www.yourdomain.com/landingpage). Hope this makes sense.